# Telerik Kendo Grid Rebind Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to filter the data from outside kendo grid. After getting right data, I am not able to see filtered data on UI.

```
$scope.kendogridOptions.dataSource.read(); - Not working out
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you able to provide more context to the problem? How are you attempting to apply the filtering? Are you expecting the filtering to happen serverside or clientside? What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the demos on the kendo ui site for filtering? https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter

Comment: I am trying to add filter through dropdown and onchange event I am passing filter to kendo. I am getting correct data but UI is not refreshing. 

I am doing it server side. I have gone through all the demos available at site but no help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the grid UI after read from datasource:

```
$scope.kendogridOptions.refresh();
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $scope.kendogridOptions.refresh is not a function.

@Javier I am using kendo grid as below:
`<div kendo-grid="grid" k-options="kendogridOptions"></div>`

`$scope.grid.refresh() - not working`

Thanks !

Comment: I don't know the specifics for Kendo Angular version. What does $scope.grid returns?

As I know in Kendo UI version:

`grid.dataSource.read();
grid.refresh();`

Comment: Thanks ! I am using kendo with JQuery now. It's working fine.

Comment: Nice! Feel free to upvote my answer if it was useful for you.